# How to use awscli inside python script?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm using aws ec2 service with awscli. Now I want to put all the commands I type in the console into a python script. I see that if I write `import awscli` inside a python script it works fine but I don't understand how to use it inside the script. For instance how do I execute the commands `aws ec2 run-instances <arguments>` inside the python script after `import awscli`? Just to make it clear, I'm not looking for a solution like `os.system('aws ec2 run-instances <arguments>')`, I'm looking for something like

```
import awscli
awscli.ec2_run-instances(<arguments>)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The CLI would be more suited for the shell prompt, for a better python API, check the boto library. This example shows how to launch an instance: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ec2_tut.html

Comment: except the boto library cant do some things that the awscli library can do. e.g. s3 sync.

Answer (score 25):

You can do it with brilliant [sh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh) package.
You could mimic python package with sh doing wrapping for you.

```
import sh
s3 = sh.bash.bake("aws s3")
s3.put("file","s3n://bucket/file")
```

Comment: The `sh` package is definitely interesting. Thanks for the pointer. But it is [not for Windows](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/faq.html?highlight=windows#will-windows-be-supported) though (will use the package for my *nix platforms)

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, due to lack of features and strange limits of boto3

Comment: This only outputs things like "<Command '/usr/bin/bash aws s3 list'>" instead of expected aws output

Comment: I get `STDERR: /usr/bin/bash: aws s3: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 18):

Boto3 doesn't have everything the cli has so you may have to use something from the cli in a script once in a blue moon. I can't find an analog for aws deploy push in boto3 for example so here is how I push to s3 with the cli from a python script. Although to Julio's point, I use boto for everything else.

```
import subprocess

cmd='aws deploy push --application-name SomeApp --s3-location  s3://bucket/Deploy/db_schema.zip --ignore-hidden-files' 
push=subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
print push.returncode
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can run `aws cli` command by using `subprocess` in python script.
For instance, suppose to get the `s3` bucket list.
Then,

```
import subprocess

push=subprocess.call(['aws', 's3', 'ls', '--recursive', '--human-readable', '--summarize'])
```

or

```
import subprocess

push=subprocess.run(['aws', 's3', 'ls', '--recursive', '--human-readable', '--summarize'])
```

Wish help for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use awscli direclty in python

```
from awscli.clidriver import create_clidriver
cli_driver = create_clidriver()
result = cli_driver.main(args=["s3api", "list-buckets"])
```

That way you trigger the command but the result will only contain the return code. I haven't found a way to capture the actual output from the tool. Additionally the instance will exit if things go wrong.

So, I don't recommend using this. Just wanted to add this for informational purpose

Comment: Just in case you *want* to go this path (like I did, when [writing a daemon for AWS CLI](https://github.com/janakaud/aws-cli-repl)), you can capture outputs/errors by overriding `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`

Answer (score 0):

Fix/example to the answer of smokeny using [sh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh). As an answer since I can't comment yet and edit is not working.

```
from sh import aws
aws("s3","cp","s3://folder/", ".", "--recursive", "--exclude", "*", "--include", "*.txt")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).