# Move a whole folder from local to S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I have to move a folder from my local to s3.
I would like to know if there is a way to do so.

My folder contains nested sub-folders with files inside (generally .pdf or .doc or docx).

I know I can move a single file from local to s3 by using `s3fs` (https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html):

```
S3FileSystem.put(filename, path, **kwargs)  Stream data from local filename to file at path
```

My code looks like

```
def upload_data(filepath, file_name):
    s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
    s3_path = f"name-of-my-bucket/{file_name}"
    s3.put(filepath, s3_path)
```

**HOWEVER** this allows me to upload a single file. I want to send a whole folder.

I can do it recursively, adding each file one by one, but:

1) I think that it would be easier if I could send the folder.

2) It would be harder to mantain the structure of the folder. Meaning that my local file `folders/subfolders/myfile.pdf` is going to be saved in s3 as `mypdf.pdf` rather than `folders/subfolders/myfile.pdf`

Comment: Side-note: `s3fs` is not a standard way to use Amazon S3. It is recommend to use boto3, which is the official AWS SDK for Python. There is no AWS API call to move multiple files, hence @Seth's suggestion to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which has recursive code to move multiple files. Alternatively, you can simply loop through your input files and copy each file to S3. There is no need to create the target directory in S3, you can simply specify the full target path.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is fairly old, and possibly this functionality didn't exist at the time of asking, but using `s3fs` you can simply just set `recursive=True`

```
def upload_data(filepath, file_name):
    s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
    s3_path = f"name-of-my-bucket/{file_name}"
    s3.put(filepath, s3_path, recursive=True)
```

Comment: Can you set an ACL in calls to `S3FileSystem.put`? Not seeing anything in the docs or source code.

Answer (score 1):

using the AWS CLI, you can use the `cp` command with the `--recursive` flag:

```
aws s3 cp folders s3://mybucket/ --recursive
```

Comment: Thanks. However I am not using AWS CLI.

Comment: yes... but maybe [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23778442/how-to-use-awscli-inside-python-script) may let you use CLI from within your Python code?

Answer (score 1):

The core [AWS S3 API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Operations.html) has no function that lets you upload more than one file at a time.

Since all of the higher level implementations of this API tend to mirror the main APIs S3 offers.  This includes boto3 and s3fs, they don't add such a feature.  If you can't use the AWS cli for some reason, you will need to upload one file at a time, and take care to mirror the local file structure to the remote S3 uploads yourself.

If you do implement this yourself, you'll need to decide the rules for changing local filenames to S3 keys, and probably want to look into using multithreading or multiprocessing to upload a few files at once.